# Replacing @tags from form input with values from the database

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am writing an @tagging system in which someone posts some text inside a comment box like: Please @mike read this. @paul also. Then the comments appears with the @tags replaces with values selected from a particular database containing @tags and their actual values.  The comments then appear like this: Please Mike Smith read this. Paul Hay also. The @tags will be replaced with values from the database.

This is what I have done so far.

```
$comments = "Please @mike read this. @paul also";
$pattern = '/\B@[^\B]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $comments, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE tagged = '$value[$key]'";
foreach ($pdo ->query($sql) as $row){
$name = $row['name'];
$username = $row['username'];
$comments = preg_replace('/[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/', '<a href='.$username.'>'.$name.'</a>', $comments );
}
echo $comments;}
```

So far, this is not outputting anything reasonable, rather what it gives is just the plain comments.
Please correct me where necessary. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$comments = "Please @mike read this. @paul also";
$pattern = '/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/'; # Changed
preg_match_all($pattern, $comments, $matches);

# print_r($matches[0]); --Output> Array ( [0] => @mike [1] => @paul )

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {   

    $newValue = str_replace('@'," ", $value);# added

    # echo $newValue; --Output> mike paul

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE tagged = '$newValue' "; # Changed

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){

        $name = $row['name'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $link = "<a href=".$username.">".$name."</a>"; # added
        $comments = preg_replace('@', $link, $comments );

    }

    echo $comments;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdulla for the answer. But    echo $comments outputs the original $comments contents. But the echo $newValue works perfectly. I triggered an error in $sql (I altered $newValue). Then the replacement worked, but with same contents. Pls any more idea?

Comment: I tried tweaking the codes and I then observed that actually, the query runs only once with the ***first match***. Then all the replacements are done with the results (from the first match). Please any more directives?

Comment: @Ukamike i got. **Change this** `$comments = preg_replace('@', $link, $comments );` ***to this*** `$comments = preg_replace($value, $link, $comments );`

Comment: Please Mike Smith read this. Mike Smith also. where _Mike Smith_ are links to the user profiles. Mike Smith's link was the first match

Comment: @Ukamike post it with ` stat and `end

Comment: Please [Mike Smith](http://www.esperasoft.com/users/mike_smith/) read this.  [Mike Smith](http://www.esperasoft.com/users/mike_smith/) also

Comment: after this `$comments = preg_replace($value, $link, $comments );` what is output??

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern for the initial preg_match is wrong for what you are seeking.

It should be something more like this:

```
$pattern = '/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/';
```

Then you would have the following value for `$matches`:

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(5) "@mike" 
    [1]=> string(5) "@paul" 
  } 
}
```

So you would only need to remove the `@` symbol unless your usernames are stored in the database with them.. Your foreach would look more like this:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
  $match = trim($match,'@'); // remove @ sign
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE tagged = :username";
  $results = $pdo->fetchAll($sql, ['username' => $match]);
  // now run foreach on $results...
}
```